# How do I use an anonymous function as an event handler for a DOM element in JavaScript?

Tags: debugging, event-handling, keyboard-events, silent, dom-events

I am writing a keypress event handler using an anonymous function expression:

```
btnuser.onkeypress = function (event) {
                       alert("Hello");
                     };
```

But it is failing silently.

Can anyone help me see what's wrong with this code?

Comment: btnuser is a button? If yes, it is more logical to use it with inputs

Comment: If `btnuser` is a button then nothing. But you have to activate it with the keyboard. Use `onclick` to respond to mouse clicks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. its txtuser which is text input type. I want to execute function expression code onkeypress event in text input.

Comment: I can think of lots of things which *might* be wrong, but there isn't enough detail in the test case to tell which (if any) of them it is. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming `txtuser` is an ID attribute value, the syntax should be as follows:

```
document.getElementById("txtuser")
```

rather than

```
txtuser
```

Also, make sure of the following:

- The script tag is defined after the element in question in the source
- The [browser supports](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) the `onkeypress` event for the key in question

**References**

- [Event handlers on elements, Document objects, and Window objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects)